# How to generate multi flavor apk by selectively bundling the dependency library?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

My android app depends on multiple android library (say A,B,C,D). I would like to generate different apks out of them say apk1 needs to consume only on A,B and apk2 needs to consume B,C.

I've explored the option of Android's [product flavor](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors) concept by doing something like this,

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {...}
    buildTypes {
        debug{...}
        release{...}
    }
    // Specifies one flavor dimension.
    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        demo {
            // Assigns this product flavor to the "version" flavor dimension.
            // If you are using only one dimension, this property is optional,
            // and the plugin automatically assigns all the module's flavors to
            // that dimension.
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
            versionNameSuffix "-demo"
        }
        full {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".full"
            versionNameSuffix "-full"
        }
    }
}
```

Now it's generating apks with multiple products but it is including all libraries for each flavor. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flavor-specific directives for your `dependencies`. Instead of `implementation`, for example, you would use `demoImplementation` and `fullImplementation`. The `demo` builds would include the `demoImplementation` dependencies, while `full` builds would include the `fullImplementation` dependencies.

The [documentation page that you linked to](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#dependencies) shows an example, using a `free` flavor:

```
dependencies {
    // Adds the local "mylibrary" module as a dependency to the "free" flavor.
    freeImplementation project(":mylibrary")

    // Adds a remote binary dependency only for local tests.
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // Adds a remote binary dependency only for the instrumented test APK.
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```